# Should file example.com/phpmyadmin/js/messages.php be visable on the web?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin on a Ubuntu 14.04 server a while back. Today I was checking out the Apache logs and someone was requesting example.com/phpmyadmin/js/messages.php

I noticed it's visible on the web. I started looking around and I noticed this page is visible on other sites as well -- sites that are not mine.

Is this a security issue I should be concerned with?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't a security issue -- it's just a list of message strings and doesn't directly reveal any sensitive information about your system.

It's probably possible for an attacker to determine which version of phpMyAdmin you're running by looking at that page, but I wouldn't worry about seeing these requests in your log file. Of course, you should keep up with security updates, but that's just general good advice and not directly related.